# Vaadin Flow: How to consume dragged file

Tags: drag-and-drop, vaadin

I have a section (DropTarget) where the user can drop several items from within my application.
This works fine.

Now I would also like to allow the user to drag files to that DropTarget.

The drop listener that I registered gets notified when I drag a file to the DropTarget, but - as far as I see - does not offer any possibility to consume the dragged file.

Anybody knows how to get this running?

Using **Vaadin flow 22.0.7**

Comment: To drop files you should use the upload component. Maybe this example can help you: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/large-upload-area

Answer (score 1):

When you create an Upload component, you can specify a `Receiver`. You can pass one as a constructor parameter or via `upload.setReceiver(Receiver)`. There are different types of Receivers depending on your use case; you can use a `MemoryBuffer` if you are ok with putting all of the data in your server memory, but there are other options, like `FileBuffer`, as can be seen here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/upload/#handling-uploaded-files-java-only ; you can implement your own `Receiver` as well.

The `Receiver` gives you access to the actual streaming content of the file. Typically, you want to access the data in some stage of the upload process, which you can do through different upload listeners. If you just want to deal with it once the upload is fully complete, you can use a `SucceededListener`:

```java
        MemoryBuffer memoryBuffer = new MemoryBuffer();
        Upload upload = new Upload(memoryBuffer);
        upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
            InputStream fileData = memoryBuffer.getInputStream();
            String fileName = event.getFileName();
            File targetFile = new File("C:/tmp/" + fileName );
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                outStream.write(fileData.readAllBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Implementing your own `Receiver` gives you more flexibility on how you want to handle the `OutputStream` from the upload, and of course you might not want to save the upload as a physical file, but put it directly in a database for example.